# How do I make my editText get selected on first click?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a ListView with EditTexts.  When i click a textbox for the first time, it gets selected, the keyboard pops out and then the textbox gets unselected.  However, once the keyboard is loaded, the textbox is selected. Here's my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/borrowerName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="14sp"
     >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loanAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="14sp"
     >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/installmentNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/estimatedTotal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    >
</TextView>  

</LinearLayout>

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/repaymentAmount"
    android:layout_width="75sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textSize="12sp"
     >
</EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried the following things :

adding the following tags to my RelativeLayout and EditText

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

adding this in my code after the listAdapter is set : `getListView.requestFocus()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of adjustpan.
Please check the below link for more info

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/134260

Answer (score 0):

In your layout you can use the [requestfocus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html) tag :

In your example :

```
<!-- [...] -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- [...] -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/repaymentAmount"
        android:layout_width="75sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="12sp">

        <requestfocus/>

    </EditText>

    <!-- [...] -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Also in your code you should call requestFocust() on the editText object and not the list view.

Comment: what kind of error do you get ? Also what version of Android are you targeting?

Comment: i had put the <requestfocus /> tag inside the <EditText> - i'm developing for version 2.3.3

Comment: ok.. setting the `<requestFocus />` in my xml gives a runtime error. setting the `requestFocus()` in the ListAdapter sets the focus to the last EditText and pops out the keyboard onload.  The keyboard should popout only after the user clicks an EditTest